# cfapi CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS calls back repeatedly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, minifilter

I'm working with the cfapi and are attempting to extend the sample project available here https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror

Specifically we are looking to implement the CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS to provide directory content on-demand. Our callbacks are registered like so:-

```
CF_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION FakeCloudProvider::s_MirrorCallbackTable[] =
{
    { CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS, FakeCloudProvider::OnFetchPlaceholders },
    { CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_DATA, FakeCloudProvider::OnFetchData },
    { CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_CANCEL_FETCH_DATA, FakeCloudProvider::OnCancelFetchData },
    CF_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION_END
};
```

The OnFetchPlaceholders method calls CfExecute() to respond to the callback with an array of placeholders for the associated files in the server directory.

```
CF_OPERATION_INFO opInfo = { 0 };
CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS opParams = { 0 };

opInfo.StructSize = sizeof(opInfo);
opInfo.Type = CF_OPERATION_TYPE_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS;
opInfo.ConnectionKey = callbackInfo->ConnectionKey;
opInfo.TransferKey = callbackInfo->TransferKey;

opParams.ParamSize = sizeof(opParams);
opParams.TransferPlaceholders.CompletionStatus = status;
opParams.TransferPlaceholders.Flags = CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAG_NONE;
opParams.TransferPlaceholders.PlaceholderArray = placeholders;
opParams.TransferPlaceholders.PlaceholderCount = placeholdersCount;
opParams.TransferPlaceholders.PlaceholderTotalCount.QuadPart = placeholdersCount;

winrt::check_hresult(CfExecute(&opInfo, &opParams));
```

Unexpectedly, with just three files in the server directory and no subdirectories the OnFetchPlacehodlers function is called many times in quick succession (457 times in the test I just carried out) - to the extent where Explorer stops responding for a while. Strangely the number of times that the method is called seems to vary between about 200 and 500 but there doesn't seem to be any discernible pattern.

I've tried setting the flag `CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAG_DISABLE_ON_DEMAND_POPULATION` in the callback and when I do this we are only called once but once set we are never asked again for the placeholders even if we have new ones to provide.

Comment: Can you show a reproducible sample (or edits you have made based on CloudMirror sample) and steps to reproduce this issue? "*Unexpectedly, with just three files in the server directory and no subdirectories*" do you want to sync from client to server?

Comment: Sure. I'm looking to sync both ways eventually but for now just provide content from the server (which may change). Example project is here https://github.com/legsak1mbo/CSMirrorCloud

Comment: Thanks for code sample. However, it use some preview features so I can't compile it successfully. How do you trigger OnFetchPlaceholders callback?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I'm not sure what preview features I was using though...? I've switched to VC++ and created a sample which also exhibits the same issue. https://github.com/legsak1mbo/VCCloudMirror

I found that when run with a "server" directory of two files the OnFetchPlaceholders was called back over 2000 times. Essentially I'm expecting this to be called when the user navigates into the folder which does happen but I can't figure out why it then repeats so many times.

Comment: Just to follow from my last, you'll need to edit the hard-coded client/server locations in the example project:-

`if (FakeCloudProvider::Start(L"C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\MirrorServer", L"C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\MirrorClient"))
`

Comment: I can reproduce this issue now. Check my answer for more detailed information.

Comment: @RitaHan Where is your answer? It's better to write your answer here so that other people can find it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe folder only needs to be populated once during the first access, then you will need use other methods to make it's contents in sync(e.g. pull the server periodically).

In my experience with the API, if you do not disable the on-demand population, every access to this folder by the **explorer.exe** or **SearchProtocolHost.exe** ( the Windows Index Service) will trigger a new **FetchPlaceholders** callback, which I believe is the reason why the callback got triggered repeatedly, this not only impact the system performance, will also increase the loads of your server.

If you do need **"revoke"** the **CF_OPERATION_TRANSFER_PLACEHOLDERS_FLAG_DISABLE_ON_DEMAND_POPULATION**, just call the [CfUpdatePlacehoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder) API and pass in the [CF_UPDATE_FLAG_ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_POPULATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_update_flags#constants) flag, this will re-enable the on-demand population, and any future access to this folder will trigger the FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS callback again.

Comment: Really interesting information. I wonder why this is not mentioned in the official docs.